# sqlite после удаления из базы ее размер не меняется

Tags: c#, sqlite

Подскажите от чего происходит подобное явление:
У меня есть база Sqlite, я пишу в нее рад данных в определенную таблицу, после удаляю не нужные строки с помощью запроса:

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM Smile_Data WHERE SMALL_NAME = '{0}'", asset.Value);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Transaction.Commit();
```

Проверил в DB browther for SQLite - удаленных данных нет в моей таблицы, однако размер файла базы данных неизменен. Использую C#. System.Data.Sqlite.

Comment: А почему Вы считаете, что размер файла обязан измениться? Вы уверены, что Вас бы устроила база данных, любое удаление из которой занимало бы несколько секунд (или больше, если база действительно большая?), необходимых для полной перезаписи файла базы?

Comment: а почему он должен измениться?

Comment: До этого просто использовал базу как склад данных  но не оперировал с ней удаляя данные из нее, считал что размер уменьшится так как данные внутри файла уменьшатся. В общем думал что после команды удаления размер файлика автоматически сжиматься будет., а как оказалось нужно специальную команду ему давать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При удалении из базы, записи физически не удаляются, а лишь помечаются как удалённые. Это сделано для минимизации времени выполнения операций с базой. Если вы хотите уменьшить размер, то после команды удаления данных, выполните "упаковку" своей базы. Для этого используйте команду [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html):

```
cmd.CommandText = "vacuum;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```